# Jest testing: How do I correctly write expect assertions witin a setTimeout?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, jestjs, settimeout

I want to JEST test a React Component which updates state after a timeout both before and after rendering state. The expect() assertion works fine in a test() but breaks when used inside a SetTimeout callback. An error states that expect is not defined within the setTimeout callback.

I have created a sandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-delayed-render-test-j5b7l

Simple component update state after SetTimeout.

```
// delayed.js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const Delayed = () => {
  let [value, setValue] = useState("foo");

  useEffect(() => {
    let handle = setTimeout(() => {
      setValue("bar");
    }, 3000);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(handle);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>MyPromise</h1>
      <p>value = {value}</p>
    </>
  );
};
```

Simple test asserts the component before and update timeout

```
// delayed.test.js

import React from "react";
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import { Delayed } from "./delayed";

let container = null;
beforeEach(() => {
  container = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});
afterEach(() => {
  unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  container.remove();
  container = null;
});

it("checks initial value", async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    render(<Delayed />, container);
  });
  expect(container.textContent).toContain("foo");
});

it("checks final value", async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    render(<Delayed />, container);
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    // this doesnt get executed!
    // error: expect is not defined
    expect(container.textContent).toContain("1234");
  }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

this is easily fixed passing in done as a param on the test.

```
it("checks final value", async (done) => {
  await act(async () => {
    render(<Delayed />, container);
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(container.textContent).toContain("bar");
    done();
  }, 3000);
});
```

as described here:

https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/test-asynchronous-code-jest